# Modify schema name of postgresql db from "public" to "my-project"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-migration

I use `ActiveRecord` to migrate the changes to postgresql db. The schema name by default is "public". Where is the best way to rename this to "my-project-name".?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such method in `ActiveRecord::Migration` to alter scheme name, but you able to use [`plain sql command`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-alterschema.html).

First generate migration file:

```
$> bundle exec rails g migration RenameSchema
```

Then open it and add:

```
class RenameSchema < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute "ALTER SCHEMA you_old_name RENAME TO you_new_name" 
  end

  def down
    execute "ALTER SCHEMA you_new_name RENAME TO you_old_name" 
  end
end
```

With that migration you can change name and rollback it back.

<sub>Note: You must own the schema to use ALTER SCHEMA. To rename a schema you **must also have the CREATE privilege for the database.**</sub>